# Syntax Error in Update Query (VB.Net)

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Please help me. My project uses an access database. This is my code:

```
Try
            Dim SqlQuery As String = "UPDATE Penawaran SET UP = '" & box_up.Text & "', Dari = '" & box_dari.Text & "', Hal = '" & box_hal.Text & "', No_Reference = '" & box_no_reference.Text & "', Email = '" & box_email.Text & "', CC = '" & box_cc.Text & "', No = '" & box_no.Text & "', Bahan_Proses = '" & box_bahan_proses.Text & "', Jumlah = '" & box_jumlah.Text & "', Harga_Satuan = '" & box_harga_satuan.Text & "', Total = '" & box_total.Text & "', Sub_Total = '" & box_sub_total.Text & "', Total_PPN = '" & box_ppn_10_persen.Text & "', Total_Semua = '" & box_total_semua.Text & "', Terbilang = '" & box_terbilang.Text & "', Note = '" & box_note.Text & "', Nama = '" & box_nama.Text & "', Bagian = '" & box_bagian.Text & "' WHERE Kepada = '" & box_kepada.Text & "'"
            Dim SqlCommand As New OleDbCommand
            With SqlCommand
                .CommandText = SqlQuery
                .Connection = Database
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            MsgBox("Data yang anda pilih sudah berhasil di ubah & simpan ke dalam sistem.")
            Call Sett_pnwrn()
            'Me.button_delete.Enabled = False
            ' Me.button_edit.Enabled = False
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Why it doesn't work?
This is the error message :

```
Syntax error in update statement.
```

What should I do?

Comment: `what should i do`  a) format your post and b) use SQL parameters

Comment: format your code.Nobody wants to heart their eyes.This has been discussed several times what is sql injection.still I see how this is not taken care of.

Comment: in fact, i used data type in "short text" (access database. mdb format). What do you mean "use SQL parameter?" i don't understand what you say

Comment: In fact, you could not have done any research on this.  If you had, you would find that almost universally answers tell you not to build SQL this way.  It leads to SQL Injection, datatype conversions and - you guessed it - syntax errors from mismatched ticks.  Examine posts #1, 2 and #4 under **Related** on the right

Comment: Please learn about parametric queries. And format your kilometric code line.